# Button will not click on HTML local website. I am starting a "counting" project and I am running a test

Tags: javascript, html, css

I expected that if I clicked "increment" button on website that I will get a respond "click" as output in consol. It doesn't even show a movement of being clicked. But It works if I run the code. I am running a test and I am using VS code and Microsoft Edge for website app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="count.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>INCREMENT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>People entered:</h1>
        <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
        <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
        <script src="count.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.75),rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.75)),url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495313196544-7d1adf4e628f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=871&q=80");
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#increment-btn {
    background: darkred;
}

#save-btn {
    background: darkgreen;
}
```

```
// document.getElementById("count-el") .innerText = 5

function increment() {
    console.log("clicked")
}

console.log("clicked")

// I also tried this code below

function increment() {
    
}

console.log("clicked")
```

Answer (score 1):

just make a css script for

```css
button:active {
   background-color: red;
```

so that the color changes while it is being pressed.

Comment: Thank you Ariel. That was a good idea

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are redefining the `increment` function. Also, you print out to the console outside of the function, which causes the code to print to the console as soon as it loads. I removed the redefinition of the function, and it works as you expected. Try it out. If it is still doesn't work for you, better attach the structure of files, maybe you are loading the wrong script.

```js
function increment() {
    console.log("clicked")
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.75),rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.75)),url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495313196544-7d1adf4e628f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=871&q=80");
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#increment-btn {
    background: darkred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="count.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>INCREMENT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>People entered:</h1>
        <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
        <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
        <script src="count.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I ran the code snippet and it worked but it won't work for me when I run it. I think something is wrong with my VS code

Comment: It finally worked but not how I understood it. I opened the page then right-clicked for "inspect" it showed on the console every time I clicked it. But the button still doesn't look like I am clicking it. It doesn't move it hover.